# How to pass javascript variables to external css files?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am new in programming and web-design, I am trying to create a website. My plans for its appearance is [image: this]

So, the code that i use is

```
<body>
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>



<script>
        function getWidth()
        {
            xWidth = null;
            if(window.screen != null)
                xWidth = window.screen.availWidth;

            if(window.innerWidth != null)
                xWidth = window.innerWidth;

            if(document.body != null)
                xWidth = document.body.clientWidth;

            return xWidth;
        }
        function getHeight() {
            xHeight = null;
            if(window.screen != null)
                xHeight = window.screen.availHeight;

            if(window.innerHeight != null)
                xHeight =   window.innerHeight;

            if(document.body != null)
                xHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

            return xHeight;
        }
</script>
</body>
```

After that i have created a .css file (empty yet). So, i want to create a website that takes the available width and height from the reader's screen and then after calculating the numbers show the divs relative to the available width and height, for example the little box will have height=width=5%available.width_of_screen. Every little box will be a project or a post.

**So, my question is:How can i pass the data of variables in the external css for calculating the numbers for my website?**

Thanks, Gabriel

Comment: Its better to hide the div in javascript instead of doing the changes in css.

Comment: Its hard to pass the values to external css file using javascript.  If you want to make changes to the css, do it from javascript or use jquery.

Comment: Standard CSS does not accept variables.  You should learn how to use percentage units. media queries and other relative layout techniques in regular CSS without variables.  You probably don't need calculations and variables to do what you're trying to do if you learn the proper pure CSS to express your layout.

Comment: @jfriend00 percentage units in an external css file or inline? Should i keep width and height in a variable for my purposes or not?

Comment: @jfreind00 If i want every little box to be relative to the width of the available screen, how can i do this without the variables?

Comment: @gabriel - please read about using percentage units in CSS.  Using pure CSS (inline or external - no difference), you can make a box be a percentage of your parent's width. If your parent is the whole width of the screen, then you've made your box be a percentage of the screen width.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, so you think that i can manage what i want only with css, right? Is this the proper way to build a website? Only with css?

Comment: @gabriel - I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but you certainly don't need javascript to make a grid layout that scales to its container.   Start with a [Google search for "how to make a grid in CSS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+grid+in+CSS&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=how+to+make+a+grid+in+CSS&aqs=chrome.0.57l2j5j0j62l2.2921&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @jfriend00 Well i tried to make a little box of width:5%; but if i want to make the height exactly the same as the width which is relative to the width of the body, how can i manage to do this without variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can set css variables using jQuery like this:

```
$("p").css({"background-color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"});
```

In this case you would replace "yellow" and "200%" with variables.

Comment: Sorry for my question, but what is jQuery exactly? This code is for the html file right? Is this working for external css file?

Comment: @gabriel It is a JavaScript library that makes using JavaScript easier or more productive in some cases.

Comment: @AlexW thanks! So, javascript can be executed in any .css, .html file? Where should i execute the above code?

Comment: @gabriel No. JavaScript has to be executed within `<script></script>` tags that are usually inside of the `<head></head>` tags of an HTML page. JQuery is just JavaScript

Comment: @gabriel http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works Good tutorial and info on JQuery.

Comment: It doesn't touch any css files, it injects the styles into the selected objects of the page.  You have a big hill in front of you but it's worth the climb.